# Как правильно разработать instagram php парсер

Tags: php, парсер, api, instagram

Собираюсь сделать инстаграм парсер для того, чтобы можно было вручную фильтровать профили из базы быстро и удобно. Думаю это должно выглядеть так: человек, который будет заниматься ручной фильтрацией, вставляет в поле список инстаграм логинов и нажимает кнопку "отобразить профили". Парсер, думаю на пхп будет брать каждую строку, затем, используюя апи инстаграма получать информацию о каждом профиле:

```
- аватар
- био
- ...
- 5 последних постов
```

Таким образом для каждого профиля парсер будет делать запрос к инстаграм апи и выводить профили по типу галлереи, для человека, который будет видеть профили и отмечать, если они подходят под его критерии галочкой. На каждую страницу допустим будет 100 профилей, затем 2 страница и так далее.

Вопрос в архитектуре: при запросе к инстаграм апи и получении информации, следует ли сначала сохранять полученные данные в базу данных или выводить их на html-страничку на лету? И вообще нужны ли здесь базы данных?

Comment: а зачем базы данных тут.

Comment: и зачем вообще тут php если есть api и js

Comment: подключите vue js или angular 1 версии и будет отличное spa

Comment: впринципе логично, попробую тогда разобраться с js. Если работали с инстаграм апи, подскажите, там это можно будет как-то многопоточно реализовать чтобы хорошая скорость была?

Comment: ну у js один поток поэтому не скажу как это исправить. ну думаю в апи есть метод который возвращает коллекцию пользователей то просто делать запрос к нему и все

Comment: а в чем смысл ангуляра и других фреймворков и почему нельзя сделать на голом js с инстаграм апи?